# calling serializer in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, post, serialization

I am having some problems with serializer. I'm calling a post method which I want it to call the serializer. Also I want to have the user sent to the serializer. my post method is:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ResourceListSerializer(context={'request': request}, data={})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(creator=request.user)
```

but it does not seem to be getting the data in serializer. in the serializer, self.validated_data seems to be empty. this is the code on the serializer:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Update `project` and `resource_type` fields in database.
    """
    resources = self.validated_data.get('resources')
    if resources is not None and len(resources) > 0:
        self.validated_data['project'] = self.validated_data['resources'][0].project
        self.validated_data['resource_type'] = self.validated_data['resources'][0].resource_type

    try:
        project = self.data.get('project')
        return super(ResourceListSerializer, self).save(**kwargs)
    except:
        try:
            project = self.validated_data['project']
            return super(ResourceListSerializer, self).save(**kwargs)
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Resource List should belong to a Project.")
```

any suggestion on how to call the serializer properly?

Comment: You're explicitly passing an empty dict to the serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is it the part on data={} ? I thought context has all the necessary info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `data` when instantiating your serializer, not `context`.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ResourceListSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(creator=request.user)
```

You only need `context` to pass *extra* context. Unless you have custom code in your serializer that accesses `self.context`, you don't need it.